# Css background image different on different width

Tags: html, css

What I was trying to do is have 2 divs with the same class side by side, one big in width and one small but both with the same background image.

The problem is when I use this code:

```
.div {
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: -40px;
    color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: url(/images/title_background.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

The result is:
[image]

The first div looks good but the seccond one the background repeats, and if I change the `backgroud-size` to fill the seccond one the first one looks stretched and weird.

**is it possible to have both with nicely fit background image withou having 2 diffent classes?**

Comment: Have you tried to use 'background-size: cover' instead? Might work better.

Comment: @Hoshts ye it worked :x such a simple thing and it bugged me for so much time, ty.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `background-size: cover;` in order for the background to scale to the container.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) is a great resource for these kind of problems.